# Uncaught TypeError: Reflect.defineMetadata is not a function on Angular 7 Production Build

Tags: angular, metadata, typeerror, production

I am trying to deploy a production build of my Angular 7 app to Azure. I was able to easily deploy it when running `ng build` but when I attempted the full `ng build --prod` I receive this error below in console and the page does not load. This also happens when running the app on a localhost server as well.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Reflect.defineMetadata is not a function
```

[image]

I have searched, but I cannot find a reference to this exact error. I see most of the results are for this: `Uncaught TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Make sure that you have [**`reflect-metadata`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) installed. Also try adding this line to your `polyfills.ts` file:

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
```

OR

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Ideally, this(the second `import` statement) is already a part of the `polyfills.ts` file.

That should make it work.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I only had zone.js imported into my polyfills.ts. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: Thanks, I solved with `import 'reflect-metadata'` (angular 8.2.x) after the importing of `zone.js`.

Comment: I had this issue for the Elastic APM RUM agent in Angular 7.1.4.
The fix was the same:
In Polyfills.ts i added `import 'reflect-metadata';` which fixes the error.

Answer (score 6):

DON'T INSTALL whole core-js, can install

```
npm i reflect-metadata
```

then simply import in polyfills.js

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

in this case you don't need to install whole core-js because only reflect-metadata needed. :)

Answer (score 5):

The import in polyfills.ts is not contained in a default Angular project anymore because Angular only needs it for dev environment.

If you need the polyfill, e.g. for modules like `class-transformer`, you can add it to the polyfills.ts:

`npm i core-js -S`

`import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';`